# what's wrong with my python list output

Tags: python

my code is something like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
x={22025: ['abc'], 22026: ['efg', 'xyz']}
c={}
z=[]
for k,v in x.items():
   for i in v:
       c['test_suite']=i
       c['barcode']=k
       z.append(c)
print z
```

the out put is

```
[{'test_suite': 'xyz', 'barcode': 22026}, {'test_suite': 'xyz', 'barcode': 22026}, {'test_suite': 'xyz', 'barcode': 22026}]
```

but I would expect it to be

```
[{'test_suite': 'abc', 'barcode': 22025},{'test_suite': 'efg', 'barcode': 22026},{'test_suite': 'xyz', 'barcode': 22026}]
```

Comment: You are reusing the same dictionary over and over again. Appending it to a list does not create a copy.

Comment: I duped you to the canonical 'how do I copy a dictionary' post. In this case, you'd be better of just creating a new empty dict in the loop.